# Why is this udev rule not triggering?

Tags: udev, usb-drive

I have a udev rule file located in /etc/udev/rules.d/usbmount.rules with the following content:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]", RUN+="/tmp/debug.sh"
```

After creating the rule, I did:

```
chmod +x /tmp/debug.sh
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

The purpose of this rule is to run a script whenever a usb block device (thumb drive, hard disk, etc) is inserted. I am tearing my hair out as to why it is not triggering. A `udevadmmonitor` gives me the following when a USB hard drive dock is attached to the system on a USB 3.0 port.

```
KERNEL[367.932459] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2 (usb)
KERNEL[367.934622] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[367.935236] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0 (scsi)
KERNEL[367.935301] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/scsi_host/host0 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[367.935414] bind     /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[367.935527] bind     /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2 (usb)
UDEV  [367.937750] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2 (usb)
UDEV  [367.939195] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [367.939940] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0 (scsi)
UDEV  [367.945817] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/scsi_host/host0 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [367.947464] bind     /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [367.950394] bind     /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2 (usb)
KERNEL[368.957786] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[368.957902] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[368.957993] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_device/0:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
KERNEL[368.958128] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg0 (scsi_generic)
KERNEL[368.958250] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/bsg/0:0:0:0 (bsg)
KERNEL[368.960906] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_disk/0:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
UDEV  [368.961035] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [368.965594] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [368.971313] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_device/0:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [368.973129] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/bsg/0:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [368.975431] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg0 (scsi_generic)
UDEV  [368.976153] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_disk/0:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
KERNEL[369.010196] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:0 (bdi)
UDEV  [369.011230] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:0 (bdi)
KERNEL[369.270352] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
KERNEL[369.270455] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
KERNEL[369.276694] bind     /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [369.874116] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
UDEV  [370.252695] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
UDEV  [370.275646] bind     /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
```

Machine info:

```
OS: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Kernel: 5.4.72-v7l+
```

The sole content of debug.sh is `echo "TESTING" >> /tmp/debuglog.txt`. Debuglog.txt is not being created.

It would appear this rule is not being triggered. Why? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The **sole content of debug.sh** is `echo "TESTING" >> /tmp/debuglog.txt`.
> Debuglog.txt is not being created.

That's the issue. The kernel will not execute such shell script, because it doesn't start with the mandatory `#!/bin/bash` telling the kernel to delegate the execution to the *bash* interpreter.

This very rarely happens because most tools will use a shell to execute a command if it didn't execute immediately. Here's an example when *strace-ing* perl to execute this command (while searching without success a tool that would make execution of the script fail immediately):

```
$ strace -e execve perl -e 'exec ("/tmp/debug.sh");'
execve("/usr/bin/perl", ["perl", "-e", "exec (\"/tmp/debug.sh\");"], [/* 15 vars */]) = 0
execve("/tmp/debug.sh", ["/tmp/debug.sh"], [/* 15 vars */]) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh", "/tmp/debug.sh"], [/* 15 vars */]) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=14452, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

It attempted first to execute the script without interpreter in its first line and got:

```
ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
```

and then tried again by inserting a shell before so it works. Here `/bin/sh`,  is not even `bash` in this environment, so if the script includes `bash` constructs, it would subtly misbehave later.

Had `/tmp/debug.sh` be this (and with the `u+rx` perms):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "TESTING" >> /tmp/debuglog.txt
```

then:

```
$ strace -e execve perl -e 'exec ("/tmp/debug.sh");'
execve("/usr/bin/perl", ["perl", "-e", "exec (\"/tmp/debug.sh\");"], [/* 15 vars */]) = 0
execve("/tmp/debug.sh", ["/tmp/debug.sh"], [/* 15 vars */]) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=14474, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Then `/tmp/debug.sh` would have be executed directly by the kernel (which would have actually defered the execution to `/bin/bash`).

`udev` doesn't attempt to do this, so it requires a valid binary *for the kernel* as first file in the command. Either supplying it directly, either by supplying a script which is an adequate executable from the point of view of the kernel by starting with the `#!/path/to/interpreter` line.

Comment: "will use a shell to execute a command if it didn't execute immediately" they will only do that if `execve(2)` failed with an `ENOEXEC` error (NOT with any other errors). That's the behaviour of the `execvp(2)` library function (which perl is using). On some systems (not on linux) `execvp` will also retry (with the same path) on `ETXTBSY`.

Answer (score 0):

udev on some systems (all?) requires absolute paths for all scripts to execute. If you are executing a shell script, you must specify the shell. For this to work I had to change it to:

`ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]", RUN+="/bin/bash /tmp/debug.sh"`